# Moment convert day str into moment with only the day and time

Tags: javascript, momentjs, cypress

I'm trying to convert the string 'Wed, 11:45 pm' into a proper datetime (preferably UTC). Is it possible to do without needing the month? The proper datetime would be the upcoming Wednesday. It's Monday(23rd) today, so Wednesday would be the 25th.

```
const time = 'Wed, 11:45 pm'
const datetime = moment(time).utc() // yields 2019-09-23T05:00:00Z (todays date)
```

I need it to yield 2019-09-25T22:25:58Z (two days, wednesday, from now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question has to be split to a few steps and your requirement is not very clear.

The steps I did here is

1. Split your input to 'Wed' and '11:45 pm'.
2. Use 'Wed' to calculate the coming Wednesday (If today is wednesday then coming wednesday would still be today or the next wednesday)
3. Set 11:45 to the hour and minute.
4. Change it to the format you prefer.

I saw your tag has cypress so I wrote a cypress test with the function above.

```
describe('Find the coming Wednesday', () => {
    it('test',()=>{
        cy.visit('https://www.google.com');
        const time = "Wed, 11:45 pm";
        var returnedDatetime = findComingDate(time);
        const outputDatetime = Cypress.moment(returnedDatetime).utc().format();
        console.log(outputDatetime);
    })
})


function findComingDate(dayAndTime) {
    //split your string
    var dayAndTime = dayAndTime.split(',');
    var day = dayAndTime[0];
    var time = dayAndTime[1];
    var parts = time.match(/(\d+):(\d+) (am|pm)/);
    if (parts) {
    var hours = parseInt(parts[1]),
        minutes = parseInt(parts[2]),
        tt = parts[3];
    }
    if (tt === 'pm' && hours < 12) hours += 12;
    var days = ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'];
    var dayindex = days.indexOf(day) + 1;
    if (dayindex === 0) {
        throw ('You can only input 3 letters for the day name')
    }
    else {
        var cd = new Date();
        //use commented code below if today is tuesady and your input is tuesday and you want output is today.  
        cd.setDate(cd.getDate() + ((7-cd.getDay())%7+dayindex)%7);
        //use commented code below if today is tuesady and your input is tuesday and you want output is next tuesday. 
        //cd.setDate(cd.getDate() + (7-cd.getDay())%7+dayindex)
        //change the time 
        cd.setHours(hours,minutes,0,0);
        return cd;
    }
}
```

I tested it on 2019-9-24 with your input 'Wed, 11:45 pm' it returns UTC time
2019-09-24T11:45:00Z

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
moment('Wed, 11:45 pm', 'ddd HH:mm a')
```